# is there any ready example of firefox addon that can manipulate site content with js/css?

Tags: firefox-addon

I know there are many tutorials but they concentrate on xul, and manipulating menus and examples are overcrowded with features.

What I need is a simple extension that will for example add a red border to all `<body>` elements of every page I'm visiting and js would show me alert when a page is finished loading. Just to show that it is working and I will have a point to start learning from.

I know that there are ready extensions like greasemonkey and user css but what I intend to do is to first make such functionality raw, without overhead of yet another extension. And second to have ha proof of concept code so I can learn other features of firefox api.

I know how to write chrome/opera extension. I know all the languages needed, and how to make a mock extension, so it show up in firefox addons list. Vut the problem is that I don't know what to put where to get to the content of actual web page.

I know that there is a file called `main.js` that I'm supposed to put somewhere with code like this:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("my_script.js"),
  contentStyleFile: data.url("my_style.css")
});
```

And that begin to look familiar, like in Chrome., my script code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  alert("hello there!");
}, true);
```

But I don't know where to put these files. Are there some default location, or must I set some configuration file to let know the api where main.js is ?

I know that there are projects to make such css/js based extension simpler, like jetpack - but that still creates overhead. I want to learn, but also don't waste my time and create something useful while doing that based on the knowlegde I have from chrome API.

edit:
I found this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM - but there is nothing on where to put these files there is no example extension using these features.

edit2: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/master/examples - there is no link for these in mozdev examples, one must search this thru google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you still in need of a ready made example?

Here is a bootstrap addon template that does exactly this. You just need to edit the `addDiv` and `removeDiv` functions for starters.

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9287185

Comment: Just a note I saw you wanted to create an alert. In the addDiv function add this code if you want to see an alert: `var theWin = theDoc.defraultView; theWin.alert('hi');`

Comment: You should recommend the add-on SDK, rather than using a classic bootstrapped addon. The XUL/classic addons are slowly being deprecated, and you'll likely get breakage with e10s.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer Tim, I didn't realize this a year ago in March. I'm recommending addon sdk for framscripts now. Although this solution does work by relying on CPOWs which are not recommended though.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the Add-on SDK. Start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials)